# How can I improve this code to not delete empty cells, but just ignore them?

Tags: excel, vba

When I use my code, I get the unique values. But one of the unique values is a blank cell and the code seems to delete this cell when the values are pasted. This messes up my formulas which are linked to these unique values.

I am also wondering how to use the indirect function in vba and link the code to two specific cells to set a specific range. I will ofc give credit if someone can give me a good answer to all of this.

I have also tried to use the following excel-formula to get the unique values: 
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT($C$14&"!"&$C$15); MATCH(0;COUNTIF($B$20:B20; INDIRECT($C$14&"!"&$C$15)&"") + IF(INDIRECT($C$14&"!"&$C$15) = "";1;0);0));"")

This formula works, but my data set is somewhat large. It therefore takes a lot of time...

```
Private Sub Unique_Click()

Dim xRng As Range
Dim xLastRow As Long
Dim xLastRow2 As Long
Dim I As Integer
On Error Resume Next
Set xRng = Application.InputBox("Please select range:", "Kutools for Excel", Selection.Address, , , , , 8)
If xRng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
On Error Resume Next
xRng.Copy Range("B21")
xLastRow = xRng.Rows.Count + 1
ActiveSheet.Range("B21:B" & xLastRow).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
xLastRow2 = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
For I = 1 To xLastRow2
  If ActiveSheet.Range("B21:B" & xLastRow2).Cells(I).Value = "" Then
     ActiveSheet.Range("B21:B" & xLastRow2).Cells(I).Delete
  End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Remove the Last For Loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work:

```
Private Sub Unique_Click()

Dim xRng As Range
Dim xLastRow As Long
Dim xLastRow2 As Long
Dim I As Integer
On Error Resume Next
Set xRng = Application.InputBox("Please select range:", "Kutools for Excel", Selection.Address, , , , , 8)
If xRng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
On Error Resume Next
xRng.Copy Range("B21")
xLastRow = xRng.Rows.Count + 1
ActiveSheet.Range("B21:B" & xLastRow).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo

End Sub
```

For Loop removed that was deleting the blank cells

Try changing

```
Set xRng = Application.InputBox("Please select range:", "Kutools for Excel", Selection.Address, , , , , 8)
```

to:

```
Set xRng = Worksheets("Data1").Range("J3:J45999")
```

Comment: Thanks Mikku! The code worked perfectly:) Do you know how to edit the line set xRng to be dynamic through the indirect function? In cell C14 I have the name of the sheet where I want to get the data ("Data1") and in C15 I have the range ("J3:J45999").

Comment: Added in the Answer

Comment: The issue is that I need to make the range dynamic, and hence use the indirect function...